# Make function that limits text not show last punctuation mark

Tags: php

I have this function that limits text, lets say to 50 chars like above:

```
$bio = limit_text($bio, 50);

function limit_text($text, $length){ // Limit Text
    if(strlen($text) > $length) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, ' ', $length));
    }
    return $text;
}
```

This should echo something like:

*Hello, this is a text limited to 50 chars and it's a great ...*

**The problem is that the function shows the last punctuation mark which does not look professional. Like in this example:**

*Hello, this is a text limited to 50 chars and it has a comma at the end, ...*

Is there any way to make the function not show the last punctuation mark?

Thank you!

Comment: trim() you can list the punctuation marks you want to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$text="Hello, this is a text limited to 50 chars and it has a comma at the end.";

//$text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", " ", $text); //bad
$text=rtrim($text,",.;:- _!$&#"); // good select what you want to remove


echo $text;
```

Comment: Hello, ty very much, but I'm not sure it removes the "."

Comment: ty, it worked, I had to change the double quotes " into single quoted ' - ',.;:- _!$&#'

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done, `ctype_punct` checks for all non-alphanumeric characters in a given string.

```
function limit_text($text, $length){ // Limit Text
    if(strlen($text) > $length) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, ' ', $length));
        if(ctype_punct(substr($text,-1))
            $text=substr($text,0,-1);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return rtrim($text, ',') . '...'; // That is if you only care about the ',' character
```

Answer (score -1):

You could a function like this to parse the `$text` first:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", " ", $text);
```

Comment: You are right Dagon, though my question was a bit unclear, I am sorry... I would like to keep question marks, or exclamation points.

Comment: @webmasters then use trim() or rtrim() and select the ones you do want to remove.

Comment: Yes, `trim()` or `rtrim()` would be best in that case. I didn't realize that you were looking to keep the other punctuation marks. There's probably a way to do it with `preg_replace` using the `$` marker, but the first two options are best.